# Can't get return value from Model in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my model I have this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(options.points) as total
            FROM responses
            JOIN options ON options.option_id = responses.option_id
            JOIN questions ON questions.question_id = responses.question_id
            WHERE options.question_id = questions.question_id
            AND questions.category_id = " . $category_id .  "
            AND responses.assessment_id = " . $assessment_id;

    $results = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $results->row()->total;
```

In my helper the code is:

```
   $points = $nin->reportmodel->getTotalPointsAssessmentByCategory(100, $assessment_id);
```

When I try to display '$points' there's nothing or zero. If I move the code out of the model and put it into the helper, the code works. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the database being loaded? As a quick test, in the constructor for your model, add $this->load->database(); As a secondary, try this $this->db->query($sql)->result()[0]->total; which is what I now use for getting the first row.

Comment: I must sheepishly admit that the model WAS NOT loading the db. THanx.

Comment: You can have CI automatically load the DB for the model by passing true as the third argument when you load it in your view: $this->load->model('Model_name', '', TRUE); but I almost always have it load in the model constructor when I know other developers are going to be working on with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

Your_model.php

```
class Your_model extends CI_Model {

public function getTotalPointsAssessmentByCategory($category_id, $assessment_id) {

$sql = "SELECT SUM(options.points) as total
    FROM responses
    JOIN options ON options.option_id = responses.option_id
    JOIN questions ON questions.question_id = responses.question_id
    WHERE options.question_id = questions.question_id
    AND questions.category_id = " . $category_id .  "
    AND responses.assessment_id = " . $assessment_id;

$query = $this->db->query($sql);

$row = $query->row();

return $row->total;

}

}
```

On Controller

```
public function index() {
   $this->load->model('your_model');

   $points = $this->your_model->getTotalPointsAssessmentByCategory(100, $assessment_id);
}
```